# How to detach Angular 2 global event

Tags: angular, directive

I am writing a directive in Angular 2 that attaches an event handler with global events like window's scroll event using host attribute in the metadata section. The code is given below:

```
<html>
 ...
 <body>
    <div listen-to-scroll>
       Some big fat content is here
    </div>
 </body>
<html>
```

And the .ts file look likes for `listen-to-scroll` directive as follows:

```
@Directive({
   selector: '[listen-to-scroll]',
   host: {
     (window:scroll): '_handleScrollEvent($event)'
   }
 })
 export class ListenToScrollDirective {
    _handleScrollEvent(event: Event) {
         console.log('event occurred');
     }
 }
```

I observed that the scroll handler registered by the directive was always active. So how to deregister it from listening from scroll event? I am expecting something clean just like registering for the event via host object.

Comment: it seems there is currently no way to do this, check [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16366)

Comment: Thanks @Maximus. It seems still a dangling issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you handle it manually, you will be able to remove the listener. Try the following:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[listen-to-scroll]'
})
export class ListenToScrollDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    ngOnInit() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScrollEvent);
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScrollEvent);
    }

    private handleScrollEvent(event: Event) {
        console.log('event occurred');
    }

}
```

The implementation above will break in environments which do not have a global `window` object, so you would have to handle that. I believe when you attach event listeners in the `hosts` property, that is handled for you by Angular.

Comment: Well, you are right. I was doing the stuff similar to what you have suggested but using Renderer class which is platform agnostic. But i do not want to do that, i want to leverage the host api because it much cleaner and less code.